# Comparing Booleans and Integers

Tags: objective-c, ios, string-comparison

I use several NSComparators in my iOS app which compare objects by NSString or NSNumber properties. This is fairly easy because NSString has `caseInsensitiveCompare:` and NSNumber has `compare:`. How do I compare bools or ints though? For booleans, code could get pretty tangled quite quickly, as my comparision functions take a `(bool)ascending` parameter. I've noticed Objective C often has obscure global functions for this type of thing.

Currently I'm using this code to compare booleans:

```
NSComparator comp = ^(id id1, id id2) {
    ListItem *comp1 = nil, 
             *comp2 = nil;
    if([id1 isKindOfClass:[ListItem class]]){
        if(ascending){
            comp1 = (ListItem*)id1;
            comp2 = (ListItem*)id2;
        }else{
            comp1 = (ListItem*)id2;
            comp2 = (ListItem*)id1;
        }
    } 
    if(h1!=nil && h2!=nil){
        if((h1.isInBasket && h2.isInBasket) || (!h1.isInBasket && !h2.isInBasket)){
            return 0;
        } else if(h1.isInBasket && !h2.isInBasket) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bools (`BOOL`, `Boolean`) and integers (`int`, `long`, `unsigned`, etc.) are just plain C integral types and you compare them with the standard C comparison operators `<`, `>`, `==` etc. Same holds for `char` (also an integral type), `float`, etc. and the named variants such as `NSInteger`.

Comment: That's not really what I was hoping for, but thanks. I've added my code to the original post. Unfortunately my boolean algebra's a little rusty.

Comment: If you want a simple way to do it the following macro should do the trick: `#define COMPARE(A,B) ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a == __b ? NSOrderedSame : (__a < __b ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending; })`.

Comment: @CRD nice macro! it is missing a closing parenthesis after b in the second comparison though

Comment: @IgnacioValdivieso - Oops. I missed a closing parenthesis before the final semi-colon. Well spotted, thanks.